# MySQL queries to get latest result plus number of records

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with getting the latest record by ID and its amount of records with the same values.

My first MySQL query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM `users` 
WHERE status = '1' AND option1 = {variable from URL}
AND option2 = '1'
```

Which shows amount of records fine. And my second query is:

```
SELECT option1, option2
FROM `users` WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM `users` 
WHERE option1 = '2' GROUP BY option2) ORDER BY date DESC
```

It works fine too.

Is there any way to have merge this two requests in one? Or I'm supposed to send 2 different queries?

My table looks like:

```
option1  |  option2  |  status  |
1        |  2        |  1       |
2        |  1        |  2       |
1        |  2        |  2       |
6        |  1        |  1       |
1        |  2        |  1       |
```

Or I need to use a PHP solution to achieve this? And I want to get results as:

```
option1  |  option2  |  status  | Total  |
1        |  2        |  1       | 2      |
2        |  1        |  2       | 0      |
1        |  2        |  2       | 0      |
6        |  1        |  1       | 1      |
```

Comment: Hard to understand the example without your date column...

Answer (score 3):

May be not the nicest, but how about two `users` tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(u1.option1) AS Total, u2.option1, u2.option2
  FROM `users` u1, `users` u2
 WHERE u1.status = '1' 
   AND u1.option1 = {variable from URL}
   AND u1.option2 = '1'
   AND u2.date IN (SELECT MAX(date) 
                    FROM `users` 
                    WHERE option1 = '2' 
                    GROUP BY option2) ORDER BY u2.date DESC;
```

Depends a bit on how many records you expect.

Comment: Thank you @Trinimon but it says the error: #1052 - Column 'date' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: You're right! I forgot to add the table in the `ORDER BY` clause. Thanks for notifying!

Comment: For some reasons @Trinimon it shows me 0 results ;-(

Comment: My statement should give you an idea about how to combine two statements. As _Adam_ wrote there is something missing to give an exact answer to your question.  Looking at your result table I've the impression you are looking for a `GROUP BY` statement with a sub select that count the totals.

Comment: For me it looks like as you were searching for something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca68/1